# Fixed div in y position but not in x position depending on other div

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have a sidebar and navbar fixed, and I would like to know if it's possible to adapt the x position of the sidebar depending on the width of each articles.

HTML :

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What is "*x position*"..? How do you want to *adapt* it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about set sidebar inside article?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uekov6y/)

HTML:

```
<div id="article">article
    <div id="sidebar">sidevar
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#article
{
    margin-left: 30px;
    background: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;

}

#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;

    top: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```